# python pandas: how to grow dataframe (fast) based on non-zero columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1_xy','2_xy','3_xy','4_xy','5_xy'],
                     'a' : [1,0,1,1,1], 'g' : [1,0,0,1,0],
                     'c' : [1,0,0,0,0], 'd' : [0,1,0,1,0],
                     'e' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'f' : [0,1,0,0,0],
                     'b' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'h' : [0,1,0,0,0],
                     'i' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'j' : [0,0,1,0,0],
                     'k' : [0,0,1,0,0], 'l' : [0,0,0,0,1],
                     'm' : [0,0,0,0,1]})
```

Output:

```
        col1    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m
     0  1_xy    1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
     1  2_xy    0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
     2  3_xy    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
     3  4_xy    1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
     4  5_xy    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

and I have a code that iterates through all values of this dataframe, and based on the columns with non-zero entries I populate a second dataframe like this:

```
    import re
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col_a", "col_b"])
    cols = [name for name in data.columns if not re.search("col1", name)]
    idx = 0
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        for name in cols:
            if row[name]>0: 
                df.loc[idx] = [row[0], name]
                idx+=1
```

The result is the following:

```
        col_a   col_b
     0  1_xy    a
     1  1_xy    c
     2  1_xy    g
     3  2_xy    b
     4  2_xy    d
     5  2_xy    e
     6  2_xy    f
     7  2_xy    h
     8  2_xy    i
     9  3_xy    a
    10  3_xy    j
    11  3_xy    k
    12  4_xy    a
    13  4_xy    d
    14  4_xy    g
    15  5_xy    a
    16  5_xy    l
    17  5_xy    m
```

Now to my question: does anyone know of a method to speed up this inefficient way of producing my second dataframe?
There should at least be a way to avoid having to check each column using an if-test somehow. 
I am really anxious to improve my python coding skills - so I'm open to all sorts of interesting solutions here. I just need it to beat my current benchmark (which I'm not providing atm.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all `0` values to `NaN`, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `col1` and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `tmp`:

Notice: Another option is use subset with `mask` by `data = data[data != 0]`

```
data = data.replace({0: np.nan})
#data = data[data != 0]

df = data.set_index('col1').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['col_a','col_a','tmp']
print df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
   col_a col_a
0   1_xy     a
1   1_xy     c
2   1_xy     g
3   2_xy     b
4   2_xy     d
5   2_xy     e
6   2_xy     f
7   2_xy     h
8   2_xy     i
9   3_xy     a
10  3_xy     j
11  3_xy     k
12  4_xy     a
13  4_xy     d
14  4_xy     g
15  5_xy     a
16  5_xy     l
17  5_xy     m
```

As [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030524/python-pandas-how-to-grow-dataframe-fast-based-on-non-zero-columns/37030681?noredirect=1#comment61611795_37030681) mentioned in comment, you can use one line:

```
data[data!=0].set_index('col1')
             .stack()
             .reset_index()
             .drop([0],axis=1)
             .rename(c‌​olumns={'col1':'col_a','level_1':'col_b'})
```

Comment: one-liner: `data[data!=0].set_index('col1').stack().reset_index().drop([0],axis=1).rename(columns={'col1':'col_a','level_1':'col_b'})`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice suggestions (to both of you). I will accept your answer after I have performed some run-time tests on a large dataset. Again, thank you.